# Java REST WebService resource access statistics

Tags: java, web-statistics

I've implemented a REST web service written in Java and I'm thinking about to add the statistics gathering functionality. If it were several years ago, I would have written some method call interceptors, incremented some counters, exposed them via JMX and passed all this stuff to RRDTool or Cacti.

I don't know, and I have failed to find something related to this task, but maybe there exist some frameworks already doing this, or at least simplifying this process ?
For example, I could measure the time taken to fulfill the user request, but it's much more harder to analyze with what request parameters the method executes longer / faster.

Ideally, I'm looking for some analytics gathering framework based on annotations. I could then annotate the methods I want to gather the call statistics for, and then later, I could open the statistics in some web page and see the very detailed report.

Does something exist in nowadays similar to this ?